# Formatting file into list with price , product name and quantity

Tags: python, string

Need the most simplest and easiest way to do the following work

i have a file like this containing product name with prices.

```
blackberry 23 100 
Black shirt with hoody (small) 4 800
Pastel Paint (red) (oil) 2 600
```

how can i format these into a list like this

```
 lst=[['blackberry' ,23 ,100],['Black shirt with hoody (small)' ,4 ,800],['Pastel Paint (red) (oil)' ,2 ,600]]
```

I am trying with split its working when the product name only contain one word for example Blackberry but if more words include it don't work anymore as i am splitting with space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.rsplit`, it starts splitting over the right part of the string as many items as you provide in the second argument (first one is the splitting item), as follows:

```
l = [
"blackberry 23 100",
"lack shirt with hoody (small) 4 800",
"Pastel Paint (red) (oil) 2 600"
]

outlist = [x.rsplit(" ", 2) for x in l]
print(outlist)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/BeautifulViolentTelevisions)

Comment: But that will return each list element as string, if you need to convert the numbers to int or floats you will need additional handling.

Answer (score 0):

you can take the index from the last. for example the last index would return the price, second last would return the quantity and the rest would return the name of the product. Then when you have each items you can append them to the list.

```
    lst = []
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        for c in content:
            new = c.split()

            price = new[len(new)-1]
            quantity = new[len(new)-2]
            name = ' '.join(x for x in new[:len(new)-2])

            nlst = [name, quantity, price]
            lst.append(nlst)
```

Output:

```
[['blackberry phone', '2', '500']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've accurately described the logic issue: you need to gather all of the *words* in one phrase, rather than splitting on spaces.  Note the common characteristic of the input lines: you have words followed by two integers.  One way is to split, but then recombine all but the last two elements.  Another is to use the `rsplit` method with a limit of 2 fields to split.  The second is probably better.

You could also handle this with a regular expression (regex), but that would require learning another facility, likely more than you want right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('demo.txt') as f:  # demo.txt is your file
    lines = f.readlines()

datas = [line.strip().rsplit(' ', 2) for line in lines]
print(datas)
```

**Output**

```
[['blackberry', '23', '100'], ['Black shirt with hoody (small)', '4', '800'], ['Pastel Paint (red) (oil)', '2', '600']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a list comprehension and `str.rsplit`. We use `str.isdigit` to select items for integer conversion:

```
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""blackberry 23 100
Black shirt with hoody (small) 4 800
Pastel Paint (red) (oil) 2 600""")

res = []

# replace mystr with open('file.txt', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    for line in fin:
        res.append([i if not i.isdigit() else int(i) \
                    for i in line.strip().rsplit(' ', 2)])

[['blackberry', 23, 100],
 ['Black shirt with hoody (small)', 4, 800],
 ['Pastel Paint (red) (oil)', 2, 600]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` and `re.findall`:

```
import re
data = [re.split('(?<=[a-zA-Z\W])\s(?=\d)', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')] 
final_data = [[a, *map(int, re.findall('\d+', b))] for a, b in data]
```

Output:

```
[['blackberry', 23, 100], ['Black shirt with hoody (small)', 4, 800], ['Pastel Paint (red) (oil)', 2, 600]]
```